# In case of servlet mkdirs() always returns false..and cant create directory

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
public class CreateDirectoryExample {

  public static void createF(){
    File file = new File("C:\\Directory1");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (file.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory is created!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
        }
    }

    File files = new File("C:\\Directory2\\Sub2\\Sub-Sub2");
    if (!files.exists()) {
        if (files.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("Multiple directories are created!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create multiple directories!");
        }
    }

  }

}
```

this code works as a simple java class. but when it being called through servlet/jsp it isn't woking...

Comment: You probably don't have permission to access the path `C:\Directory2\Sub2\Sub-Sub2`

Comment: @Lino I have given the permission. And it's creating file if run the class as simple java application. but not working if we call it from servlet.

Comment: Does the servlet can even access that directory directly? Servlet run in their own context and are much of the time cut off from direct access to the system

Comment: This is due to permission problem change c drive to another one.Try creating folder manually using your file explorer.